# How do I add a meta tag in vb6?

Tags: vb6, webbrowser-control

HTMLHeadElement vb6 add meta

I have vb6(the old version) and this code
`Dim helement As HTMLHeadElement`
I would like to add this meta tag(`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`) to the document - `WebBrowser1.document`

Comment: It won't help; the VB6 WebBrowser uses an older version of IE.

Comment: Thank you. I am seeking alternatives, maybe I will have to sludge through to vb.net or gets me self a diff web control - vbRichClient5 etc.

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far so.

Comment: ok, seems like this page has the way to go

Comment: ok, seems like this page has the way to go http://vbcity.com/forums/t/49404.aspx - I changed it to this :

Comment: Dim htDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim htHead As HTMLHeadElement
    Dim htMeta As HTMLMetaElement
    '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    Set htDoc = WebBrowser1.document
    Set htHead = htDoc.getElementsByTagName("HEAD").Item(0)
    htDoc.designMode = "on"
    'Set htMeta = htDoc.createElement("META")
    Set htMeta = htDoc.createElement("META")

Comment: 'htMeta.httpEquiv = "MSThemeCompatible"
    htMeta.httpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible"
    'htMeta.content = "Yes"
    htMeta.content = "IE=edge"
    Set htMeta = htHead.insertAdjacentElement("afterBegin", htMeta)
    htDoc.designMode = "off"
    Set htMeta = Nothing
    Set htHead = Nothing
    Set htDoc = Nothing
    'getElementsByTagName("HEAD").Item(0)
    'Me.Text2.Text = WebBrowser1.document.body.innerHTML
    Me.Text2.Text = WebBrowser1.document.getElementsByTagName("HTML").Item(0).innerHTML

Comment: If it works you should post it as your own answer.  It's unreadable as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on this code -http://vbcity.com/forums/t/49404.aspx
in a DocumentComplete sub - prints out the document to text2

```
   Dim htDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim htHead As HTMLHeadElement
    Dim htMeta As HTMLMetaElement

    '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    Set htDoc = WebBrowser1.document
    Set htHead = htDoc.getElementsByTagName("HEAD").Item(0)
    htDoc.designMode = "on"
    'Set htMeta = htDoc.createElement("META")
    Set htMeta = htDoc.createElement("META")
    'htMeta.httpEquiv = "MSThemeCompatible"
    htMeta.httpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible"
    'htMeta.content = "Yes"
    htMeta.content = "IE=edge"
    Set htMeta = htHead.insertAdjacentElement("afterBegin", htMeta)
    htDoc.designMode = "off"
    Set htMeta = Nothing
    Set htHead = Nothing
    Set htDoc = Nothing
    'getElementsByTagName("HEAD").Item(0)
    'Me.Text2.Text = WebBrowser1.document.body.innerHTML
    Me.Text2.Text = WebBrowser1.document.getElementsByTagName("HTML").Item(0).innerHTML
```

Comment: I had to go through these shenanigans because I found a javascript heavy url my webbrowser seemed to choke on. Lazy loading images etc.

Comment: I accept 'my own' answer. Although this solution doesn't 'fix' my problem. Seems like the urls I parsed had timing issues, items loaded at strange times. This solution should fix rendering issues of other sites in IE.